# How can I know why the particular columns are created and according to what the columns are update in System Base Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, system-tables

I have one doubt related to SQL Server System Base Tables.

How can I know why the particular columns are created and according to what the columns are update in System Base Tables?

For example in sys.sysschobjs system base table maintaining details about all objects created in database.This table contains nsclass,pclass,status,intprop these columns. how to know about on what basis these columns has values in that ? nsclass contains 0, why 0 is updated in that column for particular object and also status column contains 1 for stored procedure why these value ? can I know about that ?

Comment: You're not supposed to be using them: "The system base tables are used only within the SQL Server Database Engine and are not for general customer use. They are subject to change and compatibility is not guaranteed." https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Further, why do you need to know what they are for?  if you have a specific question you are trying to solve, best to post that so we can advise.

Comment: just I want to know about how SQL Server managing all information about objects that are created in that server.Can i know about system base Tables ? any Sources available for that ?